# register_sidebar ignores 'id' and 'class'

Tags: theme-development, themes, widgets, register-sidebar

I am using the following to register a widget area:

```
if ( function_exists('register_sidebar') )
    register_sidebar( array(
    'name' => __( 'Footer Widgets', 'hex'),
    'id' => 'footer-widgets',
    'class' => 'footer-widgets',
    'description' => __( 'Widgets will appear in the blog, between the end of content and footer', 'hex' ),
    'before_widget' => '<li class="widget %2$s">',
    'after_widget' => '</li>',
    'before_title' => '<h2 class="widgettitle">',
    'after_title' => '</h2>'
) );
```

And both `id` and `class` are ignored, what I get is only the widgets themselves - the top element in the widget area is the `<li>`

I know I can simply wrap it in the `index.php`, where the widgets show, with a div, but isn't this suppose to do it?

Answer (score 7):

The id parameter in register_sidebar is not directly related to the html output.  It is used to identify each sidebar when the $widget_object is built.

The class should be added to the before_widget markup.

http://core.trac.wordpress.org/browser/tags/3.4.1/wp-includes/widgets.php#L1128 is where the class gets parsed.